# Firebug Console, Safari / Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

One of the best features about Firefox and Firebug is that you can see exactly what your AJAX calls responses are.

Safari and Chrome have Developer Tools, but the Console is lacking. It doesn't show anything except for warnings and errors.

Am I missing something? Without having to place a breakpoint is the script, is it possible to see the response within Safari or Chrome's Developer Tools?

To elaborate:

"Network" doesn't show you what the actual response is that I can see. It just shows all of the loaded resources.

If I make an AJAX call to a web service, I want to be able to see the JSON response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Network` tab.

[image]

Comment: Just because it's `different` doesn't mean it's `crap`.

Comment: Has nothing to do with it being different that makes it crap. It's cluttered, slower, and far less to the point. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: Chrome console is actually more powerful as it is tightly integrated into the browser engine, so it would show all requests coming in and out, including those sent by flash (which firebug cannot do) and XHRs (which firebug kinda shows, but not nicely)

Comment: @serg, all the "Console" seems to do is report high level information. And "Network" just gives a a detailed listing of all resources on the page. Where's my AJAX response?

Comment: @dcolumbus Console is showing only errors or log messages, which is logical I think. Ajax requests are under network tab (you need to have it opened before loading the page). You can filter that list by "script" type at the bottom. To see the response click on your ajax call and switch to "content" tab"

Comment: Reluctantly, I accept. It's just not nearly as simple or to the point. For my purposes, Firebug Lite it is...